# Select case * when

Tags: mysql, sql-server, select, case

I am wondeing if there is something like the title says:

```
    SELECT CASE * WHEN NULL THEN '' ELSE * END
```

I'd like to do the case conditioning for hundreds of columns so it would be handy if I can have it on SELECT * statement. Could someone advice me if there is something like that at all in Ms SQL Server or MySQL? Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't, generally, be using `SELECT *` anyway - you should name the columns you want to retrieve. This can dramatically improve performance if some columns are expensive to retrieve, or if an index includes all columns mentioned in the query.

Comment: Also, there's no such feature in SQL Server, but just to slim down your code, you might want to look into [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for your comment and I believe it's true that I shouldn't be using * to improve the performance. But I have more faith in the computer calculation speed rather than me typing a hundred of columns name into the query. And thanks for the hint. That would probably the one I am after.

Comment: In the same way that I'd advise someone to revisit their assumptions when they write queries that produce millions of rows, I'd advise the same here - do you actually need *hundreds* of columns in the result set? If this is e.g. going to a user interface, how does the user even cope with being bombarded with so much information?

Comment: This is more to the one off query and wont be embedded into any application for now, that's why i'd rather use * instead of typing all of them in. This query is used for reporting purpose, therefore i would need a complete result.

Comment: Well as a **last** resort you can use dynamic SQL to wrap all columns in `COALESCE` for you

Comment: Agree with Damien_The_Unbeliever but if you want to have dynamic sql you can use sp_executesql. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with dynamic SQL (**MySql**)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('COALESCE(`', column_name, '`,'''') `', column_name, '`')) 
  INTO @sql
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
 WHERE table_name = 'Table1';

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' FROM Table1');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: sorry for late acceptance, but I've solved the problem very similar to your answer. Thanks